# Trying to achieve SQL "WHERE IN" functionality through "LIKE"

Tags: sql

This is a pretty common topic, but I've yet to be able to find an answer that works.

I am trying to match entries in a table to a list I supply from a webpage.

Here is what works:

```
WHERE '40663953,40663951,40663949,40663781' 
LIKE '%' + cast(IDNumber as varchar(8)) + '%'
```

(I tried it with the reversed order, with the column IDNumber going first, but didn't get any results)

or

```
WHERE cast(IDNumber as varchar(8)) in 
('40663953','40663951','40663949','40663781')
```

Here's what doesn't work:

```
 WHERE  @IDNumberList LIKE '%' + cast(IDNumber as varchar(8)) + '%'
```

and

```
 WHERE cast(IDNumber as varchar(8)) in (@IDNumberList)
```

I've tried using dynamic `sql` but it's not working for various reasons. Any ideas that could save me?

Comment: What wrong with using "what works"? Where's the problem here?

Comment: I need the list of values to be dynamic.

Comment: OK then, you you better tell us what "doesn't work" means. Any errors? Have you debugged your code to see what query's actually being executed?

Comment: So why aren't you using `WHERE CAST(IDNumber as varchar(8)) IN (SELECT IDValues FROM ValuesList)`? Or using a dynamic query?

Comment: @Bohemian Sorry, I'm not getting any errors with the two that don't work, just no rows returned.

Comment: @outisnihil The values aren't stored on the Database. Well, they are, but they're pulled down to a webpage with an unrelated stored procedure. I have to take what that one pulls down and send the list as a paramater.

Comment: I think you may want to try the dynamic query then. If you are in a variant like SQL Server that has table-valued parameters (see @dasblinkenlight 's answer below) that may help you.